# Mako report translate fields for Odoo 8

Tags: translation, odoo-8, mako

Need to translate to user connected language the output of a couple of fields, from English (the value saved on DB) to Spanish for a Mako (or Jinja, I still don't understand which is which) report on Odoo V8.

I've checked in .po file that the translated terms exist but I don't know if that is the issue or not.

I've tried to use the formatLang function used in Mako for Openerp (V7) with no success results.

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the folloing way to translate your mako report on user specify language.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <%setLang(user.lang)%>
        <!--Your code added over hear -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Using **setLang** function its automatically traslate your whole report into user specify langguage and you can specify the language optations on user form or as well as preferences menu of Odoo(OpenERP).

and another things is that if you are talking about .op file its basically used for translate your Odoo fields genereate it will added in i18n directory.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)